# vanilla javascript xmlhttprequest no-cache IE11

Tags: javascript, caching, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I'm facing a problem with a cache request in IE11 for different user sessions.

When I login with user A I get some content in the response, but when I logout I keep getting the same response as I was logged. Even if I logged with user B I get the same response.

This only happens when in IE11 and when I have the developer tools closed. If they are opened I got success.
All other browsers works fine

I already settled the 'Cache-control': 'no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0’;  Pragma to no-cache and Expires to -1.

It’s a GET method.

Some of my parameters are:

```
Pragma: true,
'Cache-control': 'no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0',
Expires: '-1'
```

Anyone has any suggestions or ideas before my final solution that would to pass the timestamp as parameter in the  url request.

Thanks

Additional info [Pragma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I got was to set the `If-Modified-Since` header to 0 (zero). It seems to work fine!!